# Nilpotent matrix and Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you help me solve this problem?

Give an example of two nilpotent matrices $N_1$, $N_2$ $ \in M_{n,n}
(\mathrm{F})$ with $N_1N_2 = N_2N_1$ such that there is no matrix B with $B^{-1}N_1B$ and $B^{-1}N_2B$ both in Jordan form.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

As an example we can take the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra with the following two elements
$$
N_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \;
N_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Both matrices commute (because $N_1$ spans the center of the Heisenberg Lie algebra, so that 
$[N_1,N_2]=0$, i.e., $N_1N_2=N_2N_1$). By assumption we have $B^{-1}N_2B=N_2$, since $N_2$ is the Jordan form of $N_2$. Hence $B$ and $N_2$ commute. It is known how to find all matrices $B$ which commute with a given matrix.
A direct computation shows that such $B$ do not put $BN_1B^{-1}$ into Jordan form.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the solution.

Comment: This is very nice.